# Page can’t be found error inside Areas controller Index

Tags: .net-core, controller

I created this Area for the admin page (Areas/System) and an AdminController inside.

But when I tried to put the URL in the address as `https://localhost:44361/System/Admin` it **didn't** break inside the `Index()` function. And an error page shows **"This localhost page can’t be found"** even there's the `Index.cshtml`

On side note, this works well inside `HomeController > Index()` when you visit `https://localhost:44361`.

Below is the sample code for Areas/System `AdminController`.

```
[Area("System")]
[Route("System/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AdminController : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]`

Comment: @dropoutcoder, it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you haven't posted your Startup.Configure, more specifically app.UseMvc, but considering the fact that your HomeController/Index gets fired I think the issue might be there. Defining [Area("System")] should be enough, rest is implicit.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    //Order is important, most specific to least specific
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "MyArea",
      template: **"{area:exists}/**{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Bit more reading on areas and route configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-area-route

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got the answer. I simply removed the Route attribute and it works.

```
[Route("System/[controller]/[action]")]
```